# ListView NativeScript printing [object Object]

Tags: listview, nativescript

I am trying to use NativeScript's ListView tag and I am apparently not understanding how to use it.

In my HTML template page, I have the following snippet

```
<ListView items="{{someArray}}">
    <ListView.template>
         <Label text="{{name}}"></Label>
    </ListView.template>
</ListView>
```

My array has a single (eventually it will have more) object in it that is formatted like this:

```
array = [
    {
        name: 'A name',
        match: false,
    }
];
```

When I compile this, I get the following showing up on my emulator

[image: screenshot]

Where that [object Object] being displayed is the array that I am passing into items={{}}. I tried passing JSON.stringify(someArray) to the items just to see what would happen and it displayed every character on its own line - which makes sense, a string is just an array of characters. I can't figure out how to actually loop through the array.

I based the code on https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/list-view#define-the-listview-itemtemplate-property but I apparently don't understand what I am reading because this is not desired behavior.

I know I could render a WebView but I would rather understand what I am doing wrong.

I tried this on a test page, where I didn't have anything but the ListView on the page and I still got the same result..

Answer (score 2):

I was reading the wrong documentation and not using Angular 2 syntax

```
<ListView col="1" row="1" [items]="someArray">
     <template let-item="item">
           <Label [text]="item.name"></Label>
     </template>
</ListView>
```

Fixed it.